# Access violation error when using glut on vista

Tags: visual-c++, windows-vista, glut

I am new in OpenGL. I am using glut library in VC express edition on vista. I am getting runtime error of "access violation" on the following line

`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

Can I avoid this error somehow?

Comment: Why don't you paste some code here so we can have a look at what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

For me setting `project properties -> linker -> advanced -> data execution prevention` to `/NXCOMPAT:NO` solved the problem.